# Authorise action with CanCan through model relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I'm using CanCan and Devise for the auth processes in an app and everything is working perfectly.

However, we have a setup in which users can create lists of items.

The List model has a user_id and the auth works fine on that, but the ownership of items is handled through the List :has_many Item relationship and Item doesn't actually have a user_id column.

How does CanCan handle this?

I tried

```
can :manage, Item do |item|
  item.list.user_id = user.id
end
```

but typing the Item id on the url gives every user access to every item, regardless of the List ownership.

I couldn't find anything that seemed to cover this in the wiki on Cancan's github so hoping someone here might be able to help

Looking forward to comments
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you confuse `=` with `==`?

```
can :manage, Item do |item|
  item.list.user_id == user.id
end
```

Comment: I'm officially an idiot... can't believe I missed that.  Just shows after hours looking for something you sometimes just can't see the wood for the trees.  Thanks for pointing out the obvious so gently :)